# Site-to-site VPN between Cisco ASA and Juniper SRX

Tags: cisco, vpn, juniper

I'm trying to create route-based VPN connection between Cisco ASA and Juniper SRX, but I have a problem with ACL and Proxy IDs. Cisco ASA log states that

```
[IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Rejecting IPSec tunnel: no matching crypto map entry for remote proxy B.B.B.B/255.255.255.0/6/0 local proxy Z.Z.Z.Z/255.255.255.255/6/22 on interface comcastpublic
```

I don't know how to make B.B.B.B/255.255.255.0/6/22 and where the problem is. The aim is to pass **only SSH traffic** through this VPN.

Notation:

A.A.A.A - Juniper public IP

B.B.B.B - Juniper private IP

Y.Y.Y.Y - Cisco public IP

Z.Z.Z.Z - Cisco private IP

Juniper SRX config:

```
interfaces {
    fe-0/0/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address A.A.A.A/26;
            }
        }
    }
    fe-0/0/7 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address B.B.B.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
    st0 {
        unit 0 {
            multipoint;
            family inet {
                next-hop-tunnel 10.10.10.1 ipsec-vpn ipsec-vpn-1-cfgr;
                next-hop-tunnel 10.10.10.3 ipsec-vpn ipsec-vpn-2-cfgr;
                address 10.10.10.2/24;
            }
        }
        unit 1 {
            point-to-point;
            family inet {
                next-hop-tunnel 10.10.10.4 ipsec-vpn ipsec-vpn-remote-cfgr;
            }
        }
    }
}
routing-options {
    static {
        route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop A.A.A.1;
        route B.B.1.0/24 next-hop 10.10.10.1;
        route B.B.3.0/24 next-hop 10.10.10.3;
        route Z.Z.Z.Z/32 next-hop st0.1;
    }
}
security {
    ike {
        traceoptions {
            file size 1m;
            flag ike;
            flag next-hop-tunnels;
            flag all;
        }
        proposal ike-proposal-cfgr {
            authentication-method pre-shared-keys;
            dh-group group2;
            authentication-algorithm sha1;
            encryption-algorithm 3des-cbc;
            lifetime-seconds 3600;
        }
        policy ike-policy-remote-cfgr {
            mode main;
            proposals ike-proposal-cfgr;
            pre-shared-key ascii-text "********";
        }
        gateway ike-gate-remote-cfgr {
            ike-policy ike-policy-remote-cfgr;
            address Y.Y.Y.Y;
            external-interface fe-0/0/0.0;
        }
    }
    ipsec {
        traceoptions {
            flag all;
        }
        proposal ipsec-proposal-remote-cfgr {
            protocol esp;
            authentication-algorithm hmac-sha1-96;
            encryption-algorithm 3des-cbc;
            lifetime-seconds 86400;
            lifetime-kilobytes 28800;
        }
        policy ipsec-policy-remote-cfgr {
            proposals ipsec-proposal-remote-cfgr;
        }
        vpn ipsec-vpn-remote-cfgr {
            bind-interface st0.1;
            vpn-monitor {
                optimized;
            }
            ike {
                gateway ike-gate-remote-cfgr;
                proxy-identity {
                    local B.B.B.B/24;
                    remote Z.Z.Z.Z/32;
                    service junos-ssh;
                }
                ipsec-policy ipsec-policy-remote-cfgr;
            }
            establish-tunnels immediately;
        }
    }
    alg {
        traceoptions {
            file alg.log size 100000 files 2;
        }
        dns disable;
        msrpc disable;
        rsh disable;
        sql disable;
    }
    flow {
        tcp-mss {
            all-tcp {
                mss 1400;
            }
            ipsec-vpn {
                mss 1350;
            }
        }
        tcp-session {
            no-syn-check;
            no-syn-check-in-tunnel;
            no-sequence-check;
        }
    }   
    policies {
        from-zone guest to-zone remote {
            policy local-to-spokes {
                match {
                    source-address net-cfgr_B-B-B-B--24;
                    destination-address net-cfgr_Z-Z-Z-Z--32;
                    application junos-ssh;
                }
                then {
                    permit;
                }
            }
        }
        from-zone remote to-zone guest {
            policy spokes-to-local {
                match {
                    source-address net-cfgr_Z-Z-Z-Z--32;
                    destination-address net-cfgr_B-B-B-B--24;
                    application junos-ssh;
                }
                then {
                    permit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    zones {
        security-zone remote {
            address-book {
                address net-cfgr_Z-Z-Z-Z--32 Z.Z.Z.Z/32;
            }
            interfaces {
                st0.1;
            }
        }
        security-zone guest {
            address-book {
                address net-cfgr_B-B-B-B--24 B.B.B.B/24;
            }
            host-inbound-traffic {
                system-services {
                    all;
                }
                protocols {
                    all;
                }
            }
            interfaces {
                fe-0/0/7.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cisco ASA config:

```
ASA Version 9.0(2) 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif comcastpublic
  ip address Y.Y.Y.Y 
!
object network VPNPC
 host Z.Z.Z.Z
 description VPN PC S2S
object network REMOTE
 subnet B.B.B.B 255.255.255.0

access-list comcastpublic_access_in extended permit object SSH object VPNPC object REMOTE 

access-list comcastpublic_cryptomap_3 extended permit tcp object VPNPC object REMOTE eq ssh 

nat (private,comcastpublic) source static VPNPC VPNPC destination static REMOTE REMOTE no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (comcastpublic,private) source static any any destination static 
!
nat (private,comcastpublic) after-auto source dynamic any interface dns
access-group comcastpublic_access_in in interface comcastpublic

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite

crypto map comcastpublic_map 4 match address comcastpublic_cryptomap_3
crypto map comcastpublic_map 4 set peer A.A.A.A 
crypto map comcastpublic_map 4 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto map comcastpublic_map 4 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
crypto map comcastpublic_map 4 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
crypto map comcastpublic_map 4 set security-association lifetime kilobytes 28800
crypto map comcastpublic_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map comcastpublic_map interface comcastpublic

crypto ikev2 policy 2
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400

crypto ikev2 enable comcastpublic
crypto ikev1 enable comcastpublic

crypto ikev1 policy 1
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 28800
crypto ikev1 policy 8
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 3600
crypto ikev1 policy 100
 authentication crack
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 110
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 120
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400

!
group-policy GroupPolicy_A.A.A.A internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_A.A.A.A attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 


tunnel-group A.A.A.A type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group A.A.A.A general-attributes
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_A.A.A.A
tunnel-group A.A.A.A ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
```

Cisco log:

```
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Received local Proxy Host data in ID Payload:  Address Z.Z.Z.Z, Protocol 6, Port 22
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, QM IsRekeyed old sa not found by addr
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Static Crypto Map check, checking map = comcastpublic_map, seq = 1...
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Static Crypto Map check, map = comcastpublic_map, seq = 1, ACL does not match proxy IDs src:B.B.B.B dst:Z.Z.Z.Z
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Static Crypto Map check, checking map = comcastpublic_map, seq = 2...
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Static Crypto Map check, map = comcastpublic_map, seq = 2, ACL does not match proxy IDs src:B.B.B.B dst:Z.Z.Z.Z
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Static Crypto Map check, checking map = comcastpublic_map, seq = 3...
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Static Crypto Map check, map = comcastpublic_map, seq = 3, ACL does not match proxy IDs src:B.B.B.B dst:Z.Z.Z.Z
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Static Crypto Map check, checking map = comcastpublic_map, seq = 4...
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Static Crypto Map check, map = comcastpublic_map, seq = 4, ACL does not match proxy IDs src:B.B.B.B dst:Z.Z.Z.Z
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Static Crypto Map check, checking map = comcastpublic_map, seq = 5...
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Static Crypto Map check, map = comcastpublic_map, seq = 5, ACL does not match proxy IDs src:B.B.B.B dst:Z.Z.Z.Z
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Skipping dynamic map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP sequence 65535: cannot match peerless map when peer found in previous map entry.
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Rejecting IPSec tunnel: no matching crypto map entry for remote proxy B.B.B.B/255.255.255.0/6/0 local proxy Z.Z.Z.Z/255.255.255.255/6/22 on interface comcastpublic
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, sending notify message
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, constructing blank hash payload
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, constructing qm hash payload
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]IP = A.A.A.A, IKE_DECODE SENDING Message (msgid=d07c313e) with payloads : HDR + HASH (8) + NOTIFY (11) + NONE (0) total length : 216
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0x00007fffa28c2920, mess id 0x5ef38480)!
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, IKE QM Responder FSM error history (struct &0x00007fffa28c2920)  <state>, <event>:  QM_DONE, EV_ERROR-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_NEGO_SA-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_IS_REKEY-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_CONFIRM_SA-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_PROC_MSG-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_HASH_OK-->QM_BLD_MSG2, NullEvent-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_COMP_HASH
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, sending delete/delete with reason message
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, Removing peer from correlator table failed, no match!
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, IKE SA MM:f4ec0f2f rcv'd Terminate: state MM_ACTIVE  flags 0x00010042, refcnt 1, tuncnt 0
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, IKE SA MM:f4ec0f2f terminating:  flags 0x01010002, refcnt 0, tuncnt 0
Aug 05 05:19:23 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = A.A.A.A, IP = A.A.A.A, sending delete/delete with reason message
```

Could anybody help with this problem?

Comment: Why not forward a port to the inside and forget about the VPN entirely?
SSH is encrypted traffic so why to build a VPN just for that?

Comment: Yes, it is one of the possible solutions. But VPN is required by company management since it is more secure.

Comment: I dont see ike allowed as host inbound traffic into your zone. May be that helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASA crypto map ACLs do not support protocol traffic matching (yeah, I know). The crypto map ACL should match on network, and then either use the global `no sysopt connection permit-vpn` to apply the interface ACL to tunneled traffic (not recommended) or use a vpn-filter in your tunnel group policy to restrict traffic by protocol.

Even if the ASA did allow the protocol-based crypto ACL, your ACL as written does not match the packets being received. Your ACL matches the remote proxy on port 22, and the logs indicate the local proxy is port 22.

Comment: You're right about ACL correctness. Your solution should work. So there're 3 possible ones:  
1) Yours  
2) Adding ACL entry:  
access-list comcastpublic_cryptomap_3 extended permit tcp object VPNPC eq ssh object REMOTE. But I haven't tested it.
3) Solution proposed on Juniper Forum by aarseniev:  
set applications application my-ssh source-port 22  
set applications application my-ssh protocol tcp  
delete security ipsec vpn ipsec-vpn-remote-cfgr ike proxy-identity service junos-ssh  
set security ipsec vpn ipsec-vpn-remote-cfgr ike proxy-identity service my-ssh

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I have a very similar setup, SRX240 to partner's ASA 5510. Took us many hours of working with JTAC and Cisco TAC to get it working. In the end, we ended up going with Policy-Based VPN vs Route-Based. For some reason, SRX's only seems to do RB better with SRX or Screen OS devices. If you plan to on going from SRX to any other vendor, using route-based, good luck. Save yourself the time and headache and go policy based. I know it's not preferred as you will have many more lines of code in your policies.

If you're still sticking with RB, definitely check out the Juniper SRX Forum:

http://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/ASA-to-SRX-golden-configuration/td-p/107774

http://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/Route-Based-with-Cisco-ASA-VPN-Issue/td-p/109166

In case you change your mind, here is our PB VPN config. Unfortunately I don't have ASA side since we do not manage it:

```
set security ike proposal PH1-PSK-3DES-G5-MD5-86400 authentication-method pre-shared-keys
set security ike proposal PH1-PSK-3DES-G5-MD5-86400 dh-group group5
set security ike proposal PH1-PSK-3DES-G5-MD5-86400 authentication-algorithm md5
set security ike proposal PH1-PSK-3DES-G5-MD5-86400 encryption-algorithm 3des-cbc
set security ike proposal PH1-PSK-3DES-G5-MD5-86400 lifetime-seconds 86400
set security ike policy PARTNER-1-POLICY mode main
set security ike policy PARTNER-1-POLICY proposals PH1-PSK-3DES-G5-MD5-86400
set security ike policy PARTNER-1-POLICY pre-shared-key ascii-text "**************"
set security ike gateway PARTNER-1-GATEWAY ike-policy PARTNER-1-POLICY
set security ike gateway PARTNER-1-GATEWAY address 1.2.3.4
set security ike gateway PARTNER-1-GATEWAY external-interface ge-0/0/0

set security ipsec proposal PH2-Proposal-2 description "Generic 8HR PH2 proposal for ESP-3DES-MD5"
set security ipsec proposal PH2-Proposal-2 protocol esp
set security ipsec proposal PH2-Proposal-2 authentication-algorithm hmac-md5-96
set security ipsec proposal PH2-Proposal-2 encryption-algorithm 3des-cbc
set security ipsec proposal PH2-Proposal-2 lifetime-seconds 28800
set security ipsec policy CISCO-ASA proposals PH2-Proposal-1
set security ipsec vpn PARTNER-1-VPN ike gateway PARTNER-1-GATEWAY
set security ipsec vpn PARTNER-1-VPN ike ipsec-policy CISCO-ASA
set security ipsec vpn PARTNER-1-VPN establish-tunnels on-traffic

set security zones security-zone untrust address-book address PARTNER-HOST-1 192.168.1.0/24
set security zones security-zone untrust address-book address PARTNER-HOST-2 10.1.0.0/22
set security zones security-zone trust address-book address HOST-5 10.22.0.32/32

set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone trust policy untrust-to-trust-vpn-1 match source-address PARTNER-HOST-1
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone trust policy untrust-to-trust-vpn-1 match destination-address HOST-5
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone trust policy untrust-to-trust-vpn-1 match application any
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone trust policy untrust-to-trust-vpn-1 then permit tunnel ipsec-vpn PARTNER-1-VPN
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone trust policy untrust-to-trust-vpn-10 match source-address PARTNER-HOST-2
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone trust policy untrust-to-trust-vpn-10 match destination-address HOST-5
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone trust policy untrust-to-trust-vpn-10 match application any
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone trust policy untrust-to-trust-vpn-10 then permit tunnel ipsec-vpn PARTNER-1-VPN

set security policies from-zone trust to-zone untrust policy trust-to-untrust-vpn-1 match source-address HOST-5
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone untrust policy trust-to-untrust-vpn-1 match destination-address PARTNER-HOST-1
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone untrust policy trust-to-untrust-vpn-1 match application any
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone untrust policy trust-to-untrust-vpn-1 then permit tunnel ipsec-vpn PARTNER-1-VPN
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone untrust policy trust-to-untrust-vpn-10 match source-address HOST-5
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone untrust policy trust-to-untrust-vpn-10 match destination-address PARTNER-HOST-2
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone untrust policy trust-to-untrust-vpn-10 match application any
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone untrust policy trust-to-untrust-vpn-10 then permit tunnel ipsec-vpn PARTNER-1-VPN
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a very similar setup.  We solved this by using a vpn-filter on the ASA side.  This allowed us to ensure the interested traffic matched allowing the tunnel to come up.  Then we used the vpn-filter to only allow the specific port via the vpn-filter access-list.

Hope that helps.